# In unix my directory contains 150 files with some data.But i want to store all files data into one newfile

Tags: unix

My folder contains 150 files with data.but  want a new file with all the 150 files data into that new file

Answer (score 0):

Do not make the newfile in the current folder.

```
cat * > ../newfile
```